# How can I get the first post THIS SAME CATEGORY?

Tags: posts, navigation, post-type

How can I get the first post THIS SAME CATEGORY? It's just that now he takes the very first post that is generally in this type, but it is necessary that he takes the first post in the same category as the last

```
     if( get_adjacent_post(true, '', true) ) {
       previous_post_link('%link', '<div class="navigation-portfolio-block"><h6 class="arrow-left mobile_navigation">Previous</h6></div> ');
     } else {
      $first = new WP_Query('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $first->the_post();
      echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional WP_Query parameters like **post_per_page**

For example,

```
$my_custom_query_args =    

    array( 'posts_per_page' =>1,

       'orderby'=>'DESC'); 

$my_custom_query = new WP_Query( $my_custom_query_args );
```

Comment: So I have it, but I need to get the first post out of the category that the last!